Apexcharts chart margins and other css issues
I am trying to get the Apexcharts working for my website. I have multiple charts of different types in one page, and I need to adjust for example margins of every chart individually, backgroundcolor, border radius and so on... but I cannot seem to be able to do so. If I put every chart into one parent div separately and do some CSS styling, the first chart styling will apply to all the charts below as well, even if they have their own parent div... How can I achieve this? I searched a lot on Internet but couldn't find any solution, and their own website does not include any guide on this either... here is my example code for two charts:


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script> 
    <div id="chart" style="max-width:500px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"></div>
    <script>  
     var options = {
        series: [{
          name: 'home',
          data: [-53, -32, -33, -52],     
        }, {
          name: 'away',
          data: [44, 55, 41, 37],     
        }],
          chart: {
          type: 'bar',
          height: 220,
          stacked: true,
          background: '#eee',
          
  
        },
       colors: ['#2E93fA','#66DA26'],
        
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            borderRadius: 2,
            borderRadiusApplication: 'end', // 'around', 'end'
            borderRadiusWhenStacked: 'all', // 'all', 'last'
            horizontal: true,
            barHeight: '60%',
          },
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        grid: {
          xaxis: {
            lines: {
              show: true
            }
          },
          padding: {
   top: 20,
   right: 20,
   bottom: 10,
   left: 20,
 },
        },
        yaxis: {
          stepSize: 20,
          min:-100,
          max:100   
        },
        tooltip: {
          shared: false,
          x: {
            formatter: function (val) {
              return val
            }
          },
          y: {
            formatter: function (val) {
              return Math.abs(val) + ""
            }
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: 'footywow Rank'
        },
        xaxis: {   
          stepSize: 100,
          categories: ['footywow Rank', 'Rank as home','Rank as away','Goals Rank'],
          labels: {
            formatter: function (val) {
              return Math.abs(Math.round(val)) + ""
            }
          }
        },
       legend: {
          position: 'top',
          horizontalAlign: 'left',
          offsetX: 40
        }
        };
        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();
  </script> 

<div id="chart" style="margin:20px !important">
  
    <script>    
    var options = {
          series: [{
          name: 'Series 1',
          data: [34, 23, 33, 40],
        }],
          chart: {
          height: 380,
          type: 'radar',
          background: '#ddd',
          
        },
      grid: {
          xaxis: {
            lines: {
              show: true
            }
          },
        },
      
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
          radar: {
            size: 120,
            polygons: {
              strokeColors: '#fff',
              fill: {
                colors: ['#eee', '#eee']
              }
            }
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Chances: Result, 2.5+ goals and BTTS',
        },
        colors: ['rgb(125,10,64)'],
        
        tooltip: {
          y: {
            formatter: function(val) {
              return val
            }
          }
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: ['Both teams to score', 'Away', '2.5+ Goals FT', 'Home']
        },
        yaxis: {
          labels: {
            formatter: function(val, i) {
              if (i % 2 === 0) {
                return val
              } else {
                return ''
              }
            }
          },
          stepSize: 10,
          min:0,
          max:100,
        }
        };
        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();
      </script>  
</div>




Use different variables for each chart, you may have problems because of that and also change the id of each chart.
